# .Net Core 3.1 Using Serilog with Microsoft.Extensions.Logger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

In this application I've pulled in and setup Serilog, which works for exceptions, and I wanted to use the Microsoft's Logger with Serilog, but I can't seem to figure out how to DI it into services without this error during `dotnet build`.

I'm not sure what I'm missing to have ILogger be using an instance of Serilog?

**Error on `dotnet build`:**

```
[13:56:21 FTL] Host terminated unexpectedly
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'App.Services.MyService'.)
```

**Dependency Injection into Service:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class MyService : BaseService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyService(
        ILogger logger)
        : base(context, httpContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    // ... Removed for brevity
}
```

Implementation

```cs
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting web host");
        CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .Run();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure buffered logs are written to their target sink
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
        .UseSerilog();

private static void CreateLogger()
{
    string path = PrimeConstants.LOG_FILE_PATH;

    try
    {
        if (isDevelopment())
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating the logging directory failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }

    var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
    var outputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithMachineName()
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", $"{name.Name}")
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", $"{name.Version}")
        .WriteTo.Console(
            outputTemplate: outputTemplate,
            theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(
            $@"{path}/prime.log",
            outputTemplate: outputTemplate,
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            shared: true))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(
            new JsonFormatter(),
            $@"{path}/prime.json",
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ILogger` isn't available to DI. You can use one of the following approaches:

1. Inject `ILogger<TCategoryName>`:

   ```
    public class MyService : BaseService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
            : base(context, httpContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // ...
    }
   ```
2. Inject `ILoggerFactory` and use its `CreateLogger` method:

   ```
    public class MyService : BaseService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            : base(context, httpContext)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("<YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME>");
        }

        // ...
    }
   ```

I'd recommend option #1, unless you want full control over the log category. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-category) to learn more about what that means:

> That category is included with each log message created by that instance of `ILogger`.